# Is there a way I can override the text property of a label in XF?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's code that I have:

```
public partial class UpperLabel : Label
{
    public UpperLabel()
    {
        this.SetDynamicResource(Label.FontFamilyProperty, "Roboto-Regular");
        this.SetDynamicResource(Label.FontSizeProperty, "HeaderTextFontSize");
        this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "HeaderTextColor");
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I would like to make it so that the label always shows the text in upper case. Here's what I would like to do but I believe that's not possible given the code I have.

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(Label), default(string));


    public string Text {
        get
        {
            var value = (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value.ToUpper() : value;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Note I realize one suggestion would be to create a property called Text1 and then have that change to upper and set Text.  Also there are other solutions such as including the Label in a Grid with a Text property.  But I still wonder if anything can be done to make the label do upper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
    new public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(CustomLabel), default(string),propertyChanged: TextPropertyChanged);

    private static void TextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var label = (CustomLabel)bindable;
        label.Text = newValue.ToString().ToUpper();
    }
```